# Kubernetes .NET Core API can't communicate with services

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core

I'm facing a k8s microservice communication issue. K8S structure as below

[image]

**Fail case**

I try to call service2 from .NET Core API 1 via `http://service2:8080` (`service2` is the services name) but I get an error.

I tried to use a simple code use `HttpClient` call google.com which can successfully get response which means not about .net coding issue.

**Success cases**

1. I use ingress controller which can let .NET Core API 1 connect to .NET Core API 2.
2. I also tried login to pod1 and `curl http://service2:8080` which can successfully get response from pod2.

It seems the k8s DNS can't recognize http://service2:8080 from .NET Core api1.

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: Are these services in the same namespace? Do you have a ```NetworkPolicy``` in place?

Comment: @PavolKrajkovič Thanks for your reply. Yes, they are in the same namespace, I create this service in Azure, I believe it use the default NetworkPolicy setting from Azure...since i'm new to k8s not sure where to check from.

Comment: Update! I tried using the clusterIP call from .NET Core api 1, it can communicate with the .NET Core api 2 successfully which mean it become a DNS issue...if someone has any idea about that would be appreciated!

Comment: k8s has dns server for all resources inside the cluster. I am curious where the problem is